# Is it possible to add to the map a layer containing results from a sql query

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-desktop

I'm developping an ArcMap Extension and I need to join an existing feature class with data from a sql query located on another DBMS.

I already set up a Workspace with an OleDbWorkspaceFactory. I'm even able to add to the document any table contained in this database. I'm now trying to add a sql query to the document the same way I do it with tables. The query can be complex and include a couple of table with inner/left joins.

I looked in the ESRI documentation and I can't find the good object to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [Make Query Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Query_Table/00170000006r000000/) tool?

Comment: I really need to be able to put a full sql statement ("Select ... from ... inner join ... where ..."), like when I define a new query layer in ArcMap

Comment: Are you saying you want to automate the process of doing File>Add Data>Add Query Layer... in arcmap?

Comment: No, but I'm trying to find an arcobject that dans take an entire sql query. The Add Query dialog probably uses one of these objects

Comment: Did you check to see if [ISqlWorkspace.OpenQuery](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_query_classes/000100000322000000/) returns a featureclass when the query includes a geometry column?

Comment: ISqlWorkspace seems to the object I was looking for. Unfortunatly, it won't work with my oledb workspace(I need to support access databases too...). I will have to find another way to do this...

Comment: Did you try opening the access workspace with using an SqlWorkspaceFactory instead?  Long shot, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: I just tried, and it doesn't work

Comment: I could always dynamically create the view (with the "CREATE VIEW" sql statement) and do an OpenTable on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple tests, since my requirement is to use an OleDbWorkspaceFactory, It's impossible to add to the document the results from a query. 
The only way to add these results it to create a view from the query (CREATE VIEW statement) and then do an OpenTable on the view